# Networking fundamentals: what IP is assigned a NIC if there is no successful DHCP negotiation?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

On Windows computers, when there is **no DHCP** server found on the network interface, it gets assigned some **IP address** like:

```
169.254.x.x
```

So it is supposed you can find it on the network using tools like:

```
# netdiscover -i eth0 -r 169.254.0.0/16
```

For network **embedded devices**, like routers or access points, I usually find them :

```
# netdiscover -i eth0 -r 192.168.0.0/16
```

But I don't know what range of IPs should be used for **Linux computers**.
It seems there is none, for example:

```
$ ifconfig
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:c0:15:64:b3
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

What **range, if any**, gets assigned on Linux to a network interface card when DHCP was not performed?

What could I use this for:

- Remotely connecting to devices or computers without knowing its IP. For example, on embedded modern devices capable to run full Linux distros, like RaspBerry, for those cases when you are not in the nearby of a DHCP server.

Comment: you might want to look at zeroconf

Comment: 169.254.x.x is a [zeroconf IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking). If zeroconf is enabled, you'll get a zeroconf IP in Linux as well.

Comment: So, @muru , in my above example for `eth3`, can we say `zeroconf` was not enabled?

Comment: I think you cannot say yes _or_ no, because it's not plugged in (it would say `RUNNING`).  Auto-config addresses require duplicate detection, so they have to probe the link first. Note modern `ip link` is better, it inverts the sense and would explicitly show `NO CARRIER`.  linux ipv4 link-local pointer is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi#Obtaining_IPv4LL_IP_address).  Basically no-one enables it.  NetworkManager doesn't support it _as a fallback_ because of potential confusion, presumably it's considered too unusual to be worth the effort to provide sensible UI / UX.

Answer (score 2):

The [current version of IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) has "zeroconf" addresses built in.  If IPv6 is enabled, in general there should be a link-local address.  You can't *scan* for it as IPv6 addresses are too large.  You *should* be able to watch for automatic addresses when you turn the device on, as its kernel will probe to make sure no other device has the same address.  You can use Wireshark or maybe `tcpdump` to look for the probe packets.  This is called duplicate address detection (DAD) and uses ICMPv6.

When you connect to this address, you will additionally have to specify the network interface, e.g. `fe80::1` + `eth0` = `fe80::1%eth0`.  In web browsers I think you have to enclose the entire thing in square brackets.

---

Traditionally the link-local address will be derived from the MAC address.  If you can read off the MAC address from a label on the device, you can also calculate the IPv6 link local address.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763254/how-does-one-calculate-ones-link-local-ipv6-address
- http://ben.akrin.com/?p=1347

---

Unfortunately these addresses won't work with the traditional Linux link-local name resolution.  (Avahi doesn't support ipv6 for this and I don't think samba does either.  systemd-resolved is hopefully better at ipv6).